# UWP App on Surface Hub

Tags: uwp, surface

How to install UWP App on Surface HUB?

Checked with Windows 10 and Surface Laptop with Powershell "Run As Powershell" option.

Same option is not available with Surface HUB

Answer (score 1):

its actually pretty simple and straight forward see the docs below : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/surface-hub/install-apps-on-surface-hub